# What is Effect Hit Rate?

Tags: honkai-star-rail

Some relics have an 'Effect Hit Rate' stat. What effect is being referred to here and at what point is the hit/no-hit RNG evaluated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer in-game:

> Effect Hit Rate increases the chance of applying debuffs to enemy targets. A higher Effect Hit Rate will result in higher chances of successfully applying a debuff.

Answer (score 2):

To add a bit more colour to this, [*Effect Hit Rate*](https://honkai-star-rail.fandom.com/wiki/Effect_Hit_Rate) (EHR) impacts the calculation for any abilities or effects that describe a *base chance*.

Effects, whether applied by characters or light cones, come in two varieties: ones with a *fixed chance*, and ones with a *base chance*. For example, [Dan Heng](https://honkai-star-rail.fandom.com/wiki/Dan_Heng)'s A2 *Faster Than Light* has a 50% *fixed chance* to increase his speed after attacking. Each attack will roll exactly a 50% chance to activate the effect.

On the other hand, [Serval](https://honkai-star-rail.fandom.com/wiki/Serval)'s Skill *Lightning Flash* has an 80% *base chance* to inflict Shocked on the targets. As an effect with a base chance to happen, it's subject to this formula:

```
Chance = Base * (1 + Attacker's EHR) * (1 - Target's Effect RES) * (1 - Target's Debuff RES)
```

In this formula, [Effect RES](https://honkai-star-rail.fandom.com/wiki/Effect_RES) is a stat that varies by enemy, affecting any effects, and increasing with level. [Debuff RES](https://honkai-star-rail.fandom.com/wiki/Debuff_RES) is a stat that varies by enemy, impacting specific categories of effects.

We can illustrate this with a sample calculation. Let's take a [Yanqing](https://honkai-star-rail.fandom.com/wiki/Yanqing) with his Lv. 10 Talent *One With the Sword*. At level 10, it has a 62% *fixed chance* to perform the follow-up attack (FUA). Then, if the follow-up attack happens, it has a 65% *base chance* of inflicting Freeze.

Suppose our Yanqing, with 0 EHR, hits a Lv. 80 [Automaton Grizzly (Complete)](https://honkai-star-rail.fandom.com/wiki/Automaton_Grizzly_(Complete)). The Grizzly has a 50% Debuff RES to all crowd control, including Frozen. Additionally, at Lv. 80, it has 30% Effect RES. Plugging in all these numbers, we get:

```
Chance_Freeze = 0.65 * (1 + 0) * (1 - 0.5) * (1 - 0.3) = 0.2275
```

So our Yanqing has less than a 1/4 chance to freeze the boss, if his follow-up hits. In this case, we can also add in the 62% fixed chance of performing the follow-up attack to calculate the overall probability of an attack:

```
Chance = Chance_FUA * Chance_Freeze = 0.62 * 0.2275 = 0.14105
```

We can also calculate how much EHR he would need to guarantee the freeze:

```
EHR = 1 / (Base * (1 - Eff. RES) * (1 - Debuff RES)) - 1
    = 1 / (0.65 * (1 - 0.5) * (1 - 0.3)) - 1
    = 1 / 0.2275 - 1
    = 3.3956
```

So our Yanqing would need 339.6% EHR to guarantee freezing this enemy. If we were fighting another enemy without any RES, he would need 53.9% EHR.